# How to move web application from the IDE to standalone?

Tags: database

I created a web application through the NetBeans IDE running a glassfish server and a Java Database.

I want to now have this be standalone and run on the startup of my physical machine.
I am having trouble figuring out how to get the database set up on the server though.

On my server machine, I've got Glassfish running and I figured out where to put my war file so that it will run on the server. However I can't figure out how to get the database setup that the application needs to run.

I don't know if it has to do specifically with the glassfish server ?
Or do I need to have a separate database program along with the server ?

I believe glassfish comes with a JavaDB but i can't figure out how to actually create and configure a database. All I can do is create connection pools and resources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Oracle's [javadb page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), it's an implementation of [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

You should be able to download and run Derby directly on your machine.  The connection strings may be different than what they were when using the embedded version, but once you figure that out it should work fine.  Good luck!